# Calculating Sum of values found in a main String

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I am currently working on a Medical Dosage data. It is a big dataset/oracle table with a string variable containing millions  of records. the string variable looks like below:

```
Drug_Direction
(1 JAN) INJECT 2ML (100MG) IV/IM AM THEN 0.5ML (25MG) 20 MIN LATER, THEN 2.5ML (125MG) PM
(SEP 20, 2018) INJECT 0.3ML (30MG) ON S1, 0.6ML (60MG) ON S2 AND 2ML(200MG) ON S3
```

These are the sample records. I need to find the MG(Miligram) doses from this main string and calculate the sum. For example:

```
Required Output:
100+25+125=250
30+60+200=290`
```

Also, the string is not in a fixed format. and sometimes there are variations, such as only  2 or 1MG dose exist. In that case. I need to get only those  MG doses. I understand i would may be need to count the MG occurrences, find  the numbers and do a sum. I am working on it simultaneously.

Same Data is available in oracle too. So if there is an easier way to  do this in Oracle-sql, that is welcome too.

Comment: I don't understand. If there is a variation of 2, how will you know if it means ML or MG? And how will you know another 2, found somewhere else, is even a dose and not something else (your strings do seem to have other numbers, as in S1, S2 etc.)

Comment: hii.. variation of 2 means, sometimes there can be only 2 doses based on direction. like 0.3 ML(30MG) in AM and 0.5 ML(50MG) in PM. In this case the sum will be 30+50=80

Comment: "A big string with millions of records" "Same data is available in Oracle too". How is it available in Oracle - is it still a single string, or is each line of text in the big string a separate row in an Oracle table?

Comment: sorry for mentioning in a wrong way. its a string var with millions of records

Comment: each obs represents separate text

Comment: You're guaranteed to have the MG in the text? And you have SAS access?

Comment: yes MG is always there in Text field, right next to the numeric value. and i have SAS access too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a single text string then, in Oracle, you can use multiple recursive sub-query factoring clauses to split the string into substrings:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, '(1 JAN) INJECT 2ML (100MG) IV/IM AM THEN 0.5ML (25MG) 20 MIN LATER, THEN 2.5ML (125MG) PM'
            || '(SEP 20, 2018) INJECT 0.3ML (30MG) ON S1, 0.6ML (60MG) ON S2 AND 2ML(200MG) ON S3' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH datelines ( id, value, dt, pos, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           value,
           '\((([0-2]?\d|3[01]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) ([0-2]?\d|3[01]), \d{4})\)',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           value,
           '\((([0-2]?\d|3[01]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) ([0-2]?\d|3[01]), \d{4})\)',
           1,
           1
         ),
         1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           value,
           '\((([0-2]?\d|3[01]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) ([0-2]?\d|3[01]), \d{4})\)',
           1,
           LVL + 1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           value,
           '\((([0-2]?\d|3[01]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) ([0-2]?\d|3[01]), \d{4})\)',
           1,
           LVL + 1
         ),
         LVL + 1
  FROM   datelines
  WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           value,
           '\((([0-2]?\d|3[01]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) ([0-2]?\d|3[01]), \d{4})\)',
           1,
           LVL + 1,
           NULL,
           1
         ) IS NOT NULL
),
actions ( id, dt, lvl, actions ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         lvl,
         SUBSTR(
           value,
           pos + LENGTH( dt ) + 2,
           LEAD( pos, 1, LENGTH( value ) + 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lvl ) - pos - LENGTH( dt ) - 2
         )
  FROM   datelines
),
amounts ( id, dt, lvl, actions, amount, num_amounts, amount_lvl ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         lvl,
         actions,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( actions, '\((\d+)MG\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) ),
         REGEXP_COUNT( actions, '\((\d+)MG\)' ),
         1
  FROM   actions
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         lvl,
         actions,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( actions, '\((\d+)MG\)', 1, amount_lvl + 1, NULL, 1 ) ),
         num_amounts,
         amount_lvl + 1
  FROM   amounts
  WHERE  amount_lvl < num_amounts
)
SELECT id,
       dt,
       SUM( amount ) AS total_amount
FROM   amounts
GROUP BY id, dt, lvl;
```

**Output**:

```
ID | DT           | TOTAL_AMOUNT
-: | :----------- | -----------:
 1 | SEP 20, 2018 |          290
 1 | 1 JAN        |          250
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8fd4a1338c97167eb64a994908cae5a)*

---

**Update**

If each line is in a different row of the database table then:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, '(1 JAN) INJECT 2ML (100MG) IV/IM AM THEN 0.5ML (25MG) 20 MIN LATER, THEN 2.5ML (125MG) PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '(SEP 20, 2018) INJECT 0.3ML (30MG) ON S1, 0.6ML (60MG) ON S2 AND 2ML(200MG) ON S3' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH amounts ( id, value, dt, amount, amount_index, num_amounts ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\((.*?)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ),
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\((\d+)MG\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( value, '\((\d+)MG\)' )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         dt,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\((\d+)MG\)', 1, amount_index + 1, NULL, 1 ) ),
         amount_index + 1,
         num_amounts
  FROM   amounts
  WHERE  amount_index < num_amounts
)
SELECT id,
       MAX( dt ) AS dt,
       SUM( amount ) AS total_amount
FROM   amounts
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output**:

```
ID | DT           | TOTAL_AMOUNT
-: | :----------- | -----------:
 1 | 1 JAN        |          250
 2 | SEP 20, 2018 |          290
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f3856a47edf7736a4b129fe37827092)*

Comment: This code worked like a charm, in few seconds only. I did some minor tweaks since i don't have id column. also, yes i have each line in different row. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to do in Oracle. You could:

1. Use `REGEXP_COUNT` to count the number of occurrences of MG values in each string
2. Use `CONNECT BY` to create a row for each match
3. Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get each actual match
4. Cast the strings to numeric values and add them up

Something like this:

```
WITH test_vals AS (
    SELECT '(1 JAN) INJECT 2ML (100MG) IV/IM AM THEN 0.5ML (25MG) 20 MIN LATER, THEN 2.5ML (125MG) PM' AS drug_direction FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT '(SEP 20, 2018) INJECT 0.3ML (30MG) ON S1, 0.6ML (60MG) ON S2 AND 2ML(200MG) ON S3' FROM dual
),

match_rows AS ( /* Get a row for each match */
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           m.drug_direction,
           LEVEL AS mg_occurrance_num
    FROM test_vals m
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(m.drug_direction, '((\d+\.)?\d+)MG') /* Count number of matches in each string */
)

SELECT r.drug_direction,
       SUM(
          TO_NUMBER(
              REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                  r.drug_direction, 
                  '((\d+\.)?\d+)MG', 
                  1, 
                  r.mg_occurrance_num, /* Search for this specific occurrance */
                  '', 
                  1 /* Get first sub-group (the actual numeric value) */
              )
          )
       ) AS total_mg_value
FROM match_rows r
GROUP BY r.drug_direction
ORDER BY r.drug_direction
```

Note that this assumes all the values are in that exact format (a numeric value followed by the string 'MG').

Comment: Thank you . This worked really nicely on the sample records. I am just testing it against the full table.  It is taking time to execute, considering size of table,

Comment: can i ask you about a little detail, i just found that in some cases,.. the MG value is mentioned as 10 MG(with a space). So this code won't work there. Any solutions you may suggest

Comment: Sure, you can add ` ?` to the two regex patterns (the count then the actual match). The space matches a space character, and the question mark indicates that character may or may not be present. So, the final regex pattern would be `((\d+\.)?\d+) ?MG`. Here's a great tool for messing around with regex if you'd like to learn more: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot